# Calculating i_delta in upper confidence bound algorithm

Tags: reinforcement-learning, data-science

I wanted to apply upper confidence bound algorithm.

There is a 2 dimensional dataset in it Each user in the dataset reviewed (((all))) movies with 0 or 1 not some movies only

And i want to get the best movie

My teacher said to calculate i_delta we should divide by num_selections[movie](the number of positive reviews) is it wrong? i know that we should divide by the number of times that the users reviewed the film not the number of selection in the code because all users reviewed the all films with 0 or 1 not some users reviewed with 1 and ignore the others so it is 0

The full code

```
num_users = len(dataset['User'])

for user in range(num_users):

    selected_movie = 0

    max_upper_bound = 0

    for movie in range(num_movies):

        if num_selections[movie] > 0:

            average_reward = sum_rewards[movie] / num_selections[movie]

            delta_i = np.sqrt(1.5 * np.log(user + 1) / num_selections[movie])

            upper_bound = average_reward + delta_i

        else:

            # Initialize with a high upper bound for unexplored movies

            upper_bound = 1e400

        if upper_bound > max_upper_bound:

            max_upper_bound = upper_bound

            selected_movie = movie

    # Simulate user selection and reward (replace 'your_reward_column' with the actual column name in your dataset)

    reward = dataset.iloc[user, selected_movie]

    num_selections[selected_movie] += 1

    sum_rewards[selected_movie] += reward
```

So should I write this line

```
delta_i = np.sqrt(2 * np.log(user + 1) / num_selections[movie])
```

Or this

```
delta_i = np.sqrt(2 * np.log(user + 1) / user
```

If you don't understand read this
if the case is that there are 5 ads and we want to know the best to publish and each user enter to the website he saw one ads only and if he click on it the value will be 1 and if not the value is 0

Be careful that each user saw (((one))) ad only here
So which line i should write

The shape of the dataset
ad1 ad2 ad3 ad4 ad5
User1  0   1   0   0   0
User2 ....................